# Wifi is not showing on PureOS?

Tags: wifi, troubleshooting, pureos

Hello the option to connect to Wifi is not shown on the PureOS settings?

Which firmware should I install ?

Distro ID: PureOS
Descrip: PureOS 10 Byzantium

Releases: 10

Answer (score 1):

You have elected to use PureOS, which has, by it's primary goal, absolutely no repository of closed-source proprietary firmware blobs.

Since, to the best of my knowledge, no wifi cards with open firmware exists (at least for modern cards that need loading of firmware during initialization): There's no firmware you can load through pureos.

You could of course work *around* pureos and try to find the right firmware for your card (which you sadly don't even mention – how were we even hypothetically supposed to help you pick firmware for a card we don't know?).

But that would a) be against the very principles of the OS you freely chose to install, so probably also against your principles and b) more work and more error-prone than using a "mainstream" distro (like "proper" debian) which ships with access to the full linux-firmware tree.

Comment: Okay rookie mistake of mine. 

I just wanted an secure OS I could also use to study in school.

Which Debian distro would you recommend for an starting IT student`?

Comment: debian. simply debian.